# How to use rosinstall with articulation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install the [articulation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/articulation_tutorials/Tutorials/ArticulationWebcamDemo/) package. The documentation states you should do a svn checkout and run rosmake.

But this should now be done using rosinstall? How should this be done? Is there somewhere a clear a example of a .rosinstall file? How are missing dependencies handled then?

*In the end I just did it the old way by adding the path and ran rosmake. Only I got this error:*Error: package/stack rosgui_paramedit depends on non-existent package rqt_gui_cpp. *but should this file not be present in the core installation?*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47798/how-to-use-rosinstall-with-articulation/) by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2573 on 2012-11-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way to manage overlays and .rosinstall is to use [rosws](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) instead of doing that manually.

In general, your method also works. The tools only simplify that.

Regarding the rqt_gui_cpp warning: This is probably, because you added the trunk. If you don't need the paramedit rosgui plugin, it is safe to ignore. Otherwise, there is ros-fuerte-rqt, which contains rqt_gui_cpp.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2012-11-08**:
Thanks! But I don't get it completely yet. I checked out the whole alufr-ros-pkg trunk because articulation required freiburg_tools which is in the same svn. However I still had to add the paths to the package path to be able to execute rosmake. Is this correct or can it be done more efficiently?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-09**:
The package path handling, etc. is done automatically by rosws, if you use that. Instead of the trunk you could just have used freiburg_tools+articulation, but it's fine like this. The rosgui_paramedit/rqt_gui_cpp error is from another package in freiburg_tools that you probably don't need.